# How to execute a batch file on remote using psexec?

Tags: windows, batch-file, psexec

I have a batch script which is unzipping a folder. It looks as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e "C:\target\bin.zip"
```

the above batch script unzip the folder bin.zip to same location as that of batch file. Now, this batch script is placed on the remote machine and i have to start it there remotely . I used psexec and did following from my local machine command prompt:

```
psexec -s -i \\ip_add -u user -p pass C:\target\sample.bat
```

So, now it does not unzip any file on the remote machine. I am not getting what am i doing wrong. The batch script is perfectly working fine and i tried to verify psexec is working correctly or not by launching a calc on remote , it worked pretty well. so, please suggest what am i lacking.

Comment: `cmd /c "c:\target\sample.bat"` My guess is that psexec isn't using `ShellExececute` to trigger the process on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to launch cmd.exe from psexec to get a remote shell and then attempt to run the batch file from the command prompt